# Some problems with struct

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct student{
    char name[10];
    int  grade;
};


int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    student s[0].name = "Jack";
    cout<<s[0].name;
}
```

I want to create the struct type data `student` as an arraign. But when I did it like this, some errors appeared and I didn't know why.Following are the errors:

1.error: redefinition of 's' with a different type: 'student [0]' vs 'struct student [10]'

```
    student s[0].name = "Jack";
            ^
```

2.note: previous definition is here

```
 struct student s[10];
                ^
```

3. error: expected ';' at end of declaration

```
 student s[0].name = "Jack";
                ^
                ;
```

Comment: yeah, this does not compile, missing `;`

Comment: What errors? That's kind of important.

Comment: on a serious note, use `strcpy()`.

Comment: "Some errors appeared" isn't good enough. "Hey my car is not starting. I get an error message. Can you fix it?"

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ya, obvious in retrospect. Half the questions I've seen so far today have mentioned an error, but not said what it was. I kind of went on autopilot there.

Comment: Well, you just need to fix some of your code in order to address some of those errors.

Comment: @Carcigenicate don;t get me wrong, your comment is appropriate, OP should be posting the errors, no doubt. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. `char name[10];`:

   1. `10` characters is too short for a name.
   2. `char` assumes names are not outside ASCII or UTF-8, and it doesn't look like you're using a Unicode library.
   3. Fixed-sized arrays for storing strings is not keeping with idiomatic C++.
   4. Solution: use `std::string` or `std::wstring` - and use a Unicode library!
2. `struct student s[10]`

   1. This is not idiomatic C++. The `struct` keyword is unnecessary. Just `student s[10];` is sufficient.
   2. Again, avoid fixed-sized arrays unless you know for certain you will be using 10 records. Use `std::vector<student>` instead.
   3. You don't initialize the array, so the data-members will contain undefined/uninitialized data. Use `= {0}` to zero-out memory and/or define a `student` constructor.
3. `student s[0].name = "Jack";`

   1. This won't compile. I think you meant to put just `s[0].name = "Jack"`
   2. The assignment operator `=` is not defined (by default) for strings. Note that your struct's member type is `char` whereas a string literal is `const char[N]`, so in reality you're assigning a pointer (due to Array Decay) to a `char` member. This is a meaningless operation.
4. Your `main` does not return a value. Use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` on success. This is not strictly required, but I personally believe it's good practice to explicitly return a value.

Comment: Thanks, man.I just started to learn these things, so I can't really understand some of your words.My english is also not so good.I'll try more. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding your point nr 4. The C++ standard actually guarantees that if you fall off the end of `main` (as the *only* function) without returning a value, then it returns 0 - so that's not a bug, but well-defined behaviour.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for pointing that out, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Dai You're welcome. Btw; to be *really* pedantic, one should `return EXIT_SUCCESS`. Not all platforms use 0 (zero) to indicate success - one example being VMS.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oh wow - I never knew that one!

Comment: @Dai :) the `EXIT_SUCCESS`/`EXIT_FAILURE` macros are an often overlooked detail of the standard - and rarely relevant on most modern platforms, but they *are* there for a real reason. So use them if you aim for maximum portability :)